# Chrome extension error Package is invalid: 'CRX_HEADER_INVALID' from chrome store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I import the app locally on my machine it works fine. It also used to work on the chrome store. I recently uploaded and update and now "Package is invalid: 'CRX_HEADER_INVALID'." I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Contacted google support and they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Contacted google support and they fixed the issue.